# response.writeHead not sending post data

Tags: node.js, response

I have the following code

```
console.log(typeof(postData));
console.log(typeof(querystring.parse(postData)));
console.log(typeof(querystring.parse(postData).text));
console.log(querystring.parse(postData).text);
var stuff = querystring.parse(postData).text;
console.log(stuff);
stuff = "You've sent the text: " + stuff;
console.log(stuff);
console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
console.log(response.write(stuff));
response.end();
console.log("More text");
console.log(stuff);
```

In the console I get

```
string
object
string
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
You've sent the text: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Request handler 'upload' was called.
false
More text
You've sent the text: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

But on the webpage I see

```
You've sent the text: undefined
```

I can't figure out why my post data is not sending but the string I append it to is.

I am following the tutorial from The Node Beginner Book.

The full requestHandlers code (minus console), where start is the start page and upload is what is returned (the previous code)

```
var querystring = require("querystring");
function start(response, postData) {
var body = '<html>'+
'<head>'+
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
'charset=UTF-8" />'+
'</head>'+
'<body>'+
'<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
'<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
'<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />'+
'</form>'+
'</body>'+
'</html>';

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
response.write(body);
response.end();
}
function upload(response, postData) {
    var stuff = querystring.parse(postData).text;
    stuff = "You've sent the text: " + stuff;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end();
}
exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

Comment: Can you show us a repeatable example snippet? From what you've shown, it looks like it should work fine.

Comment: That's the thing, the snippet should work. I followed and eventually copied and pasted the entire file from the tutorial. So I'm thinking it's not a code problem but a configuration problem, or something in my data. The full requestHandler's file looks like the extra bit I've posted at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I wound up blowing away all my files and just copying and pasting in. After that worked I went back and discovered I had left an extra route line in my main server file. My guess is that it was sending the response and then  the function with the loggers was running. So the code above was running but the response was actually unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is probably not in your requestHandlers.js. Although, in your snippet you've forgot to put in the "response.write("You've sent the text: " + stuff);" line, I'm assuming this is a copy and paste error.

Your start.js file should look like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var postData = "";
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
        request.setEncoding("utf8");

        request.addListener("data", function (postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Received POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk + "'.");
        });

        request.addListener("end", function () {
            route(handle, pathname, response, postData);
        });

    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Note that the route is called in the request objects "end" handler and the postData is built up in "chunks" in the request object's "data" handler.

In your router.js file should be;

```
function route(handle, pathname, response, postData) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](response, postData);
    } else {
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
        response.writeHead(404, {
            "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
        });
        response.write("404 Not found");
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

I suppose the key here is to make sure you are passing the postData variable and NOT the request variable. I'm guessing this is what is happening in your code.

This is all on pages 51-53 of the book.

Comment: Thank you, per your advice (and copy paste comment which was correct) I went back through my code, and eventually recopied it all in. It turned out it wasn't the postData variable but that I had an extra response call so the one that I was logging was running and then being ignored (I think).

Comment: @user393001 - if you're happy :) can you mark my answer as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Another fix would be to remove the ".text" at the end of the function. I am using the same tutorial and have run into the same problem. I'm not following the tutorial 100% correctly, but I have found the removing the ".text." and stringifying returned the postData into both the console and the server webpage.

```
function enterUsers(response, postData)
{
console.log("user entered");
//response.write(query.fullname); 
//response.write("\nuser entered... ;)");
//response.write(postData); 
//response.write(querystring.parse(postData).text)

response.write("\n"+postData)
var receivedData = querystring.parse(postData);
console.log(receivedData); 
response.write("\nYou've sent the text: \n" + querystring.stringify(receivedData, '\n', ' = '));
response.end();
}
```